# Unable to copy an Excel WorkSheet from Workbook A to WorkBook B?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, interop

I am trying to copy "Config" WorkSheet from Excel file A to Excel file B using the below code but I am getting the following error:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred 
Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC**

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;

            string reportname = ServerName;
            string Destfilepath = string.Empty;
            Destfilepath = Application.StartupPath + "\\StandardReports\\" + reportname + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcelType"].ToString();


            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Destfilepath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);



            Excel.Worksheet wrkD = ((Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Config"]);            

            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            // Create a new Excel Workbook
            string SourcePath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Templet\StdReport" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcelType"].ToString();
            //string outputPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\Receipt.sdc";
            Excel.Workbook SourceexcelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(SourcePath,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


            Excel.Worksheet wksh1S = ((Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
            Excel.Worksheet wksh2D = ((Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[2]);
            wksh1S.Copy(wksh2D);// I am getting error here
```

**Note:** My motive is to copy "Config" sheet from Excel file A and add it to Excel file B. B already contains a "Config" file, I would like to either overwrite this sheet or delete and add new one from A.

Comment: As an aside, as of C# 4.0 (released 6 years ago), you don't need all the arguments / `Type.Missing`.  e.g. `excelApp.Workbooks.Open(SourcePath)` will work fine.

Comment: @CharlesMager thanks, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: The issue is likely because you're trying to copy a sheet between *different application instances*. Try opening your two workbooks in the same instance of Excel.